# How can I type an actual lambda character in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, unicode

I'm talking about this guy, right here: λ

In Microsoft Word, you can type `03BB` followed by <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to get that character.  This does not work in Visual Studio 2013.  Any ideas?

To specify: I intend to enter the 'λ' character as part of C# source code, not as part of a string literal.

Comment: Copy/paste from your Word document?

Comment: Some tips here: http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm

Comment: You can use unicode string literals: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69ze775t.aspx

Comment: @JosepValls, thanks for the comment.  I should have specified this is part of C# source code, not part of a string value.

Comment: @EricBurcham can't find a source for VS 2013 but it seems that the specification of the C# language also requires you to use unicode for identifiers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @MarkRansom - I have been copy/pasting from word, so at least I know now I'm not dumb for doing the "obvious" thing.  I am trying to avoid opening a separate application just for entering Unicode characters into source code.  On the link you sent, I have exhausted the options with no luck.  Method 1 with hex Unicode values would be ALT, 955.  This results in a lower-case lambda in Word, but not Visual Studio.  Copying from word still works, of course.  Neither the Windows Latin 1 input language or the code page 437 support the lambda, though they work for other characters.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JosepValls - The following source codes compiles and executes fine:  var λ = 15; Console.WriteLine(λ);

Comment: This also compiles and executes just fine (though it hurts my eyes): `var \u03BB = 15; Console.WriteLine(λ);` Unicode escaping is not restricted to string and character literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good question, and one that bugged me into trying to get this to work. I do second OP's comment that you can compile code with lambda characters for variables just fine.

However, after an hour of trying various methods I knew of and found for typing special characters (using Windows 8.1 Professional, Windows display language set to "English (United States)" and Keyboard layout set to "US") I could not get Visual Studio 2013 (with update 4) to type a lambda.

Although I'm not sure, I'd think that different input languages and/or keyboard layouts would change the situation, and might make this possible.

For the general case, until proven otherwise, **I'd hazard a guess that it's not easily possible**. The workarounds that probably *would* work are plugins and unicode-typing-tools. Also, if you already use it, AutoHotkey is probably capable of helping out here.

Comment: I never did get it to work either.  I spent about an hour looking through examples... It seems the standard input mechanisms work in Visual Studio but only to an extent.  For example, using Alt +0394 for a capital delta works fine, but Alt +3BB for a lower-case lambda fails.  I think it is just not tolerant of the 'B' in the hexadecimal part of the entry.  Oh well.  As an alternative, this thing works like a champ:  http://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is that **copy this symbol "λ"** from here and paste it in your VS Code editor. It works!!

Comment: This works for a one-off but is clunky and inefficient. For instance, I want to use the λ character instead of the lambda keyword in Racket. I use this regularly. Now I need to either keep my clipboard free so that it always holds "λ", or I need to go find a λ character somewhere in my project so that I can copy/paste it. Neither of these solutions work for me